# How to create bootable Windows 7 USB on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, usb, iso

I have a Windows 7 ISO which I'm trying to put on my USB to install Windows alongside ubuntu (I already know the steps to take to fix grub when I'm done) My problem is when I use unetbootin, it gets stuck on a screen that repeats automatic boot in 10 seconds infinitely, and I can't install winUSB on ubuntu 16.04.

I tried all the solutions and it works, but when I try to boot I get some error messages about realtek. Will post a screenshot when I get home.

I tried doing it for a third time and it worked, for some reason. So thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to 'Disks'.
2. Select the USB drive.
3. Restore the iso file from properties.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**mkusb** now does Win10 startup disks:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7

Extracting the iso to a NTFS formatted USB has not worked for me in years.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try install WoeUSB or WinUSB

Here the download link: https://pkgs.org/download/woeusb

Or You can install it using terminal commands (WoeUSB):

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install woeusb

WinUSB downloadlink: https://pkgs.org/download/winusb

For WinUSB use command:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install winusb

Answer (score -1):

You can use dd command in Ubuntu. The command is:

```
sudo dd if=/pathofiso of=/pathtousb
```